# shopping cart asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, shopping-cart

i have a shopping pages, but have problems with the quantity, i dont know how to pick the value of the textbox, this is my code.

```html
<table class="table table-condensed">
     <thead>
      <tr class="cart_menu">
       <td class="image">Product</td>
                            <td><div class="col-md-1"></div> </td>
       <td class="description"></td>
       <td class="price">Price</td>
       <td class="quantity">Quantity</td>
       <td class="total">Total</td>
       <td><div class="col-md-1"></div></td>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
                        
                        <!-- begin Cart -->
                        <% for(int j=0;j<NoItems;j++)
                           {
                               Label8.Text = j.ToString();
                               view();%>
                        
      <tr>
                            <td style="display:block">
                                   <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
       <td class="cart_product">                           
        <a href="#"><img src="/WebVenta/img/enrollable2.jpg" alt="" width="110"></a>                           
       </td> 
                            <td><div class="col-md-1"></div></td>
       <td class="cart_description">
                                
        <h4><a href="/WebVenta/Page/Producto.aspx">Persiana Enrollable</a></h4>
        <p><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=''></asp:Label></p>
       </td>
       <td class="cart_price">
        <p><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p>
       </td>
       <td class="cart_quantity">
        <div class="cart_quantity_button">      
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="Cantidad" class="cart_quantity_input" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>    
        </div>
       </td>
       <td class="cart_total">
        <p class="cart_total_price"><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label" autocomplete="off" size="2"></asp:Label></p>
       </td>
       <td class="cart_delete">
        <a class="cart_quantity_delete" onclick="Borrar()" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>     
       </td>
      </tr>
                        <% i++;
                           } %>

                        <!-- end -->

     </tbody>
    </table>


now in the behind code have this 

 public string[,] Carrito = new string[20, 13];
 NoItems = Convert.ToInt32(Session["NoItems"]);//its the number of differents items
 Carrito = (String[,])Session["Cart"];//its a array with all products


public void view()
{
    Label1.Text = (String)Carrito[i, 1] + "/" + (String)Carrito[i, 3] + "/" + (String)Carrito[i, 4] + "/" + (String)Carrito[i, 5] + "/" + (String)Carrito[i, 6] + "/" +
         (String)Carrito[i, 7] + "/" + (String)Carrito[i, 8] + "/" + (String)Carrito[i, 9] + "/" + (String)Carrito[i, 10];
    Label2.Text = "$" + (String)Carrito[i, 2];
    Label3.Text = "$" + (String)Carrito[i, 2];
    Cantidad.Text = (String)Carrito[i, 13];
}

public void comprar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < NoItems; a++)
    {
        
    }
}
```

now my problem its how to save the quantity of the product,

right now i dont use a database, all the information its in Sessions, the data base is in progress.

any ideas? sorry my english.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the quantity by parsing the text from `Cantidad`

```
int quantity = 0;
int.TryParse( Cantidad.Text, out quantity );
```

You should also change the `class` attribute for Cantidad to `CssClass`.